# ggplot2 geom_bar position failure

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, stacked

I am using the `..count..` transformation in `geom_bar` and get the warning
*position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals* when some of my categories have few counts.

This is best explained using some mock data (my data involves direction and windspeed and I retain names relating to that)

```
#make data
set.seed(12345)
FF=rweibull(100,1.7,1)*20  #mock speeds
FF[FF>60]=59
dir=sample.int(10,size=100,replace=TRUE) # mock directions

#group into speed classes
FFcut=cut(FF,breaks=seq(0,60,by=20),ordered_result=TRUE,right=FALSE,drop=FALSE)

# stuff into data frame & plot
df=data.frame(dir=dir,grp=FFcut)
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=dir,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..),fill=grp)) + geom_bar()
```

This works fine, and the resulting plot shows the frequency of directions grouped according to speed. It is of relevance that the velocity class with the fewest counts (here "[40,60)") will have 5 counts.
[image: Three categories of size 20 each]

However more velocity classes leads to a warning. For instance, with

```
FFcut=cut(FF,breaks=seq(0,60,by=15),ordered_result=TRUE,right=FALSE,drop=FALSE)
```

the velocity class with the fewest counts (now "[45,60)") will have only 3 counts and ggplot2 will warn that

*position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals*

and the plot will show data in this category spread out along the x axis.
[image: Four categories of size 15 each. Now the last one with three elements is not added on top of the corresponding bar]
It seems that 5 is the minimum size for a group to have for this to work correctly.

I would appreciate knowing if this is a feature or a bug in `stat_bin` (which `geom_bar` is using) or if I am simply abusing `geom_bar`.

Also, any suggestions how to get around this would be appreciated.

Sincerely

Comment: Perhaps this? `ggplot(data=df,aes(dir, fill=grp)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This occurs because `df$dir` is numeric, so the ggplot object assumes a continuous x-axis, and aesthetic parameter `group` is based on the only known discrete variable (`fill = grp`).

As a result, when there simply aren't that many `dir` values in `grp = [45,60)`, ggplot gets confused over how wide each bar should be. This becomes more visually obvious if we split the plot into different facets:

```
ggplot(data=df,
            aes(x=dir,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..),
                fill = grp)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~ grp)
```

[image: facet view]

```
> for(l in levels(df$grp)) print(sort(unique(df$dir[df$grp == l])))
[1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 10
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
[1]  2  3  4  5  7  9 10
[1] 2 4 7
```

We can also check manually that the minimum difference between sorted `df$dir` values is 1 for the first three `grp` values, but 2 for the last one. The default bar width is thus wider.

The following solutions should all achieve the same result:

**1. Explicitly specify the same bar width for all groups in `geom_bar()`**:

```
ggplot(data=df,
       aes(x=dir,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..),
           fill = grp)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 0.9)
```

**2. Convert `dir` to a categorical variable before passing it to `aes(x = ...)`**:

```
ggplot(data=df,
       aes(x=factor(dir), y=(..count..)/sum(..count..),
           fill = grp)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

**3. Specify that the `group` parameter should be based on both `df$dir` & `df$grp`**:

```
ggplot(data=df,
       aes(x=dir,
           y=(..count..)/sum(..count..),
           group = interaction(dir, grp),
           fill = grp)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much. Incidentally, my original code has dir as a categorial variable, but the plot I am working on is far more complex and also has ` coord_polar()` added. With the circular plot the discreteness in the x axis caused troubles when I added other layers to the plot. Having a continuous x axis solved those, but pherhaps that solution was premature.....

Comment: Side note: I had this issue show up while trying to pass labels to plotly. While the ggplot was fixed by specifying the width (Solution #1 above), the labels passed to plotly became NA. Solution #3 worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly solve the issue, because I also don't get what's going on with the overlapping values, but it's a `dplyr`-powered workaround, and might turn out to be more flexible anyway.

Instead of relying on `geom_bar` to take the cut factor and give you shares via `..count../sum(..count..)`, you can easily enough just calculate those shares yourself up front, and then plot your bars. I personally like having this type of control over my data and exactly what I'm plotting.

First, I put `dir` and `FF` into a data frame/`tbl_df`, and cut `FF`. Then `count` lets me group the data by `dir` and `grp` and count up the number of observations for each combination of those two variables, then calculate the share of each `n` over the sum of `n`. I'm using `geom_col`, which is like `geom_bar` but when you have a `y` value in your `aes`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(12345)
FF <- rweibull(100,1.7,1) * 20  #mock speeds
FF[FF > 60] <- 59
dir <- sample.int(10, size = 100, replace = TRUE) # mock directions

shares <- tibble(dir = dir, FF = FF) %>%
  mutate(grp = cut(FF, breaks = seq(0, 60, by = 15), ordered_result = T, right = F, drop = F)) %>%
  count(dir, grp) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n))

shares
#> # A tibble: 29 x 4
#>      dir grp         n share
#>    <int> <ord>   <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1 [0,15)      3  0.03
#>  2     1 [15,30)     2  0.02
#>  3     2 [0,15)      4  0.04
#>  4     2 [15,30)     3  0.03
#>  5     2 [30,45)     1  0.01
#>  6     2 [45,60)     1  0.01
#>  7     3 [0,15)      6  0.06
#>  8     3 [15,30)     1  0.01
#>  9     3 [30,45)     2  0.02
#> 10     4 [0,15)      6  0.06
#> # ... with 19 more rows

ggplot(shares, aes(x = dir, y = share, fill = grp)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Camille. This is very useful. I had been thinking along these lines of making the code more explicit. The thing is I am updating a plotting routine I wrote in base R in  2001 (and which has been used continuously since then), and then everything was calculated explicitly. Cumbersome, but I knew what I had.  Your solution is quite elegant, and not cumbersome at all....